# Htaccess 301 Redirect Rules / HTTP to HTTPS / non-www to www

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have an old domain where was the old site:

```
http://example-old.com/
```

Would like to do 301 redirect to new domain:

```
https://www.example-new.com/
```

How do I achieve that in .htaccess with the 301 redirect rules.

And needs to match these requirements:

If someone types in the URL

```
http://example-old.com/ >>> https://www.example-new.com/

https://example-old.com/ >>> https://www.example-new.com/

http://www.example-old.com/ >>> https://www.example-new.com/

https://www.example-old.com/ >>> https://www.example-new.com/

">>>" - means 301 redirect
```

When I put it in the .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.example-new.com/
```

It works for

```
http://example-old.com/ >>> https://www.example-new.com/
```

The rest is a blank white page or connection error.

I do not need to pass any arguments or query string - because the URL (query string) on the new site is different - so I just need those 4 to be working and pointing to new site domain and always HTTPS (443 port).

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: No, but Jimmy solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding this to your .htaccess file instead of what you have here. It should redirect all requests to the new address.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule .* https://www.example-new.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```